# android studio openstreetmap viewer and POM

Tags: android-studio, osmdroid

New to android studio (2.3.1) I managed to follow the Android tutorial to get a text field into another screen/activity. I also did a little app to display a google map. Wanting offline maps I tried the openstreetmap viewer from the osmdroid-master.zip file.
I get this error while syncing

Error:Cannot get property 'pom' on extra properties extension as it does not exist.

Any one know where this error comes from. 
Also are there any real step by step osmdroid tutorials. I found a "step by step" tutorial by haakseth which basicly said get the tiles, add these libraries, add this bit of code and there you go.

Comment: For an osmdroid tutorial see [How to use the osmdroid library](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/How%20to%20use%20the%20osmdroid%20library). This doesn't cover offline tiles, though.

Comment: I'm stuck with the same issue. Looks like the project's structure is not up to date.